# Flatten array with objects into 1 object

Tags: javascript, lodash, flatten

Given input:

```
[{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }]
```

How to return:

```
{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```

For arrays [it's not a problem](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten) with lodash but here we have array of objects.

Comment: Is it even ok to ask on SO for npm packages?

Comment: No. You can describe the problem you're having, like you just did, and if the answer happens to be "install this npm package" then that's fine; but you shouldn't specifically ask for a package to solve the problem.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
let merged = Object.assign({}, ...arr); // ES6 (2015) syntax

var merged = Object.assign.apply(Object, arr); // ES5 syntax
```

Note that `Object.assign` is not yet implemented in many environment and you might need to polyfill it (either with core-js, another polyfill or using the polyfill on MDN).

You mentioned lodash, so it's worth pointing out it comes with a `_.assign` function for this purpose that does the same thing:

```
 var merged = _.assign.apply(_, [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }]);
```

But I really recommend the new standard library way.

Comment: Shouldn't you do `Object.assign({}, ...arr)`?!

Comment: @Bergi I can if I want to preserve the input of `assign` intact. I certainly don't have to if I don't. Since that was not a requirement I didn't treat it as such.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Yes, preserving the input is a best practise :-) It can lead to ugly bugs when it's unexpected.

Comment: My linter throws a `Expected at least 1 arguments, but got 0 or more.` if I didn't add the extra {}; `Object.assign({}, ...ids`.

Comment: @jprio No, it works only on a single level. `Object.assign` is not recursive.

Comment: Nasty mutation without following suggestion from @Bergi -also, this answer works with an array of objects too. For googlers, this is similar to Ruby's .reduce(&:merge)

Answer (score 5):

With lodash, you can use [merge()](https://lodash.com/docs#merge):

```
var arr = [ { a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 } ];
_.merge.apply(null, [{}].concat(arr));
// → { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```

If you're doing this in several places, you can make `merge()` a little more elegant by using [partial()](https://lodash.com/docs#partial) and [spread()](https://lodash.com/docs#spread):

```
var merge = _.spread(_.partial(_.merge, {}));
merge(arr);
// → { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a version not using ES6 methods...

```
var arr = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }];
var obj = {};

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var o = arr[i];
    for(var key in o) {
        if(typeof o[key] != 'function'){
            obj[key] = o[key];
        }
    }
}

console.log(obj);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yaw3wbb8/

Comment: Note that this will also copy enumerable prototype properties (which is not a problem in this particular case).

Comment: would a simple ` && !o.propertyIsEnumerable(key)` added to the if statement fix this?

Comment: Well, for... in only enumerates enumerable properties. A `Object(o).hasOwnProperty(obj)` would fix it though (ensuring it's not on the prototype) - the `Object(o)` part is to ensure we're not calling a non-existing method so that for example passing `4` would not fail (and copy nothing).

Comment: Aren't the enumerable properties the ones you would want to copy? For instance, you would not want something like `Array.prototype.length` in the object.. right? Or am I missing this entirely?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Even better: `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, i)` to ensure we're not calling a custom method or even non-function property value.

Answer (score 4):

You can use underscore.extend function like that:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var a = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }];

var result = _.extend.apply(null, a);
console.log(result); // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
console.log(a); // [ { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 } ]
```

---

And to prevent modifying original array you should use

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var a = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }];

var result = _.extend.apply(null, [{}].concat(a));
console.log(result); // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
console.log(a); // [ { a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 } ]
```

[Here can test it](http://code.runnable.com/me/VZJ500MLfDJYbZoi)

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the accepted answer, a running code snippet with ES6.

```js
let input = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }]
//Get input object list with spread operator
console.log(...input)
//Get all elements in one object
console.log(Object.assign(...input))
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got a neat little solution not requiring a polyfill.

```
var arr = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }];
var object = {};

arr.map(function(obj){
    var prop = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
    object[prop] = obj[prop];
});
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I have no idea why this was upvoted since it can't doesn't work - getOwnPropertyNames returns an array.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum For this use case it works perfectly. See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dhgsbg99/

Comment: This is just incidental since all the objects have a single property and `toString`ing the array with a single property gives the same result, try adding a property to one of the objects and see it failing: http://jsfiddle.net/zqvhceyj/

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I understand it perfectly - I was just applying a solution to the use case. I can be more generic, but the question clearly asked "for **this** input, return **this** output", I was merely doing so.

Comment: @JonathanBrooks and that's exacly what I've asked for. :-)

Comment: @Ultra Haha! That's what I gleaned from your question; I'm glad my downvotes are unwarranted :')

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice usage of `Object.assign` with the `array.prototype.reduce` function:

```
let merged = arrOfObjs.reduce((accum, val) => {
  Object.assign(accum, val);
  return accum;
}, {})
```

This approach does not mutate the input array of objects, which could help you avoid difficult to troubleshoot problems.

Comment: usefull when converting to another type of objects

Answer (score 0):

You can easily flat your object to array.

```
function flatten(elements) {
  return elements.reduce((result, current) => {
    return result.concat(Array.isArray(current) ? flatten(current) : current);
  }, []);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

6 years after this question was asked.

Object.assign is the answer (above) I like the most.

but is this also legal ?

```
let res = {};
[{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }].forEach(val => {
    let key = Object.keys(val);
    console.log(key[0]);
    res[key] = val[key];
})
```

Answer (score 0):

With more modern spread operator

```
arrOfObj.reduce( (acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, ...cur }) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  [{ a: "a" }, { b: "b" }, { c: "c" }],
  [{ d: "d" }, { e: "e" }, { f: "f" }],
  [{ g: "g" }, { h: "h" }, { i: "i" }],
];

function convertToObject(array){
  const response = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const innerArray = array[i];
    for (let i = 0; i < innerArray.length; i++) {
      const object = innerArray[i];
      const keys = Object.keys(object);
      for (let j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
        const key = keys[j];
        response[key] = object[key];
      }
    }
  }
  return response;
}

console.log(convertToObject(data));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function carParts(manufacturer, model, ...parts) {
  return { manufacturer, model, ...Object.assign(...parts) };
}
console.log(
  carParts(
    "Honda",
    "2008",
    { color: "Halogen Lights" },
    { Gears: "Automatic Gears" },
    { LED: "Android LED" },
    { LED: "Android LED1" }
  )
);
```

This is how i have done.