# Object get the value by a key

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I'm kinda stuck with an issue. This is the response for my AJAX call.

```
var test = [
  {
    "analytics.feature": "false"
  },
  {
    "demo": "true"
  },
  {
    "analytics.demo": "false"
  }
]
```

Now I want to check if analytics.demo is enabled or disabled.

Can I use _.find?

`_.find(test, {analytics.demo});` //returns error

I just want to do this

```
if(analytics.demo) {
//Do something
}
```

How do I do that? Can someone help?

Instead of iterating objects and comparing, can I use underscorejs/jQuery to get the exact value for a key?

Comment: What's wrong with plain javascript? `test[2]["analytics.demo"]` will return "false"...

Comment: The order keeps changing. Is there anyway I can search the "key" and get the value. Instead of blindly doing test[2] @nicael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const options = Object.assign(...test)
console.log(options) // { "analytics.feature": "false", demo: "true", "analytics.demo": "false" }
if (options['analytics.demo'] === 'true') {
  // ...
}
```

(Note that this uses ES6. For ES5 use `var options = Object.assign.apply(object, test)` instead, and you also need to polyfill `Object.assign`.)

This uses [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to merge the objects into one, then get the "analytics.demo" option from the new single object. It has to be accessed using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) because the key has a dot in. It is compared to the *string* `true` because `"false"` (string) is true but `false` (boolean) is false.

There is more information on SO about [flattening arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31136464/6303733) and [converting strings to booleans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/264037/6303733).

PS is there any way you can get the Ajax call to use proper booleans instead of strings? It would be easier to work with.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if any of the items in the array matches a certain condition like so:

```
var isDemoEnabled = test.some(function (item) {
    return item['analytics.demo'] === 'true';
});

if (isDemoEnabled) {
    // Do something 
}
```

If the values were boolean, you could remove `=== 'true'`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using underscore, check out the documentation regarding find:
http://underscorejs.org/#find

Find runs a predicate function for every element in an array and returns a new array that contains every value where the predicate function returned true.

In this case we want to find if the element has a field analytics.demo
To do this we can use the underscore function `_.has`:
http://underscorejs.org/#has

all in all:

```
var result = _.find(test, function(elem) {
    return _.has(elem, "analytics.demo");
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate over and check if the key is given and return then the result.

```js
function getKeyValue(array, key) {
    var value;
    array.some(function (a) {
        if (key in a) {
            value = a[key];
            return true;
        }
    });
    return value;
}

var test = [{ "analytics.feature": "false" }, { "demo": "true" }, { "analytics.demo": "false" }]

console.log(getKeyValue(test, 'analytics.demo')); // 'false' a string with this value
```