# lodash filter data by multiple filters

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this data and need to apply all the filters using lodash. The final output is blank.

```js
filters = [{'gender':'M'}, {'division':'police'}]

data = [{'name':'tom', 'gender':'M', 'division':'police'},
        {'name':'bob' , 'gender':'M', 'division':'police'},
        {'name':'dave' , 'gender':'F', 'division':'IT'},
        ]

data = _.filter(data, function(item){   
      _.forEach(filters, function(filter){     
            data_found = _.filter([item], filter)
            console.log('data_found - ', data_found)
        })        
      }) 

console.log(data)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/52k6170c/1/

Comment: The predicate you give to `filter` never returns anything. Neither of them. EDIT: I'm actually confused what should be happening, since there is a foreach continually overwriting `data_found`...whatever that is

Comment: The final output should contain all records with gender-male and division-police

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine your filters array to a single object and use that as your filter

```
combined = filters.reduce((acc,item) =>  ({...acc, ...item})) 
// combined is = {'gender':'M', 'division':'police'}

data = _.filter(data, combined)
```

if you feel like not using the rest operators, there is a lodash [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31136464/4272651) that combines the array of objects into a single object

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `_.filter` method along with the `_.every` method to filter a collection based on another collection of predicates (I'm using arrow functions here). This example also assumes your filter objects only have a single key/value pair as in your example:

```
const filteredData = _.filter(data, item => {
  return _.every(filters, filter => {
    let filterKey = Object.keys(filter)[0]
    return item[filterKey] === filter[filterKey]
  })
})
```

A cleaner solution would be to combine your filters into a single object, and use the `_.matches` method to do a comparison:

```
const filter = { gender: 'M', division: 'police' }
const filteredData = _.filter(data, _.matches(filter))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just combine both filter into one. Something like this

```
_.filter(data, function(item){
  if(item.gender === 'M' && item.division === 'police') return item;
})
```

This would give you all records with gender-male and division-police